# Converting JSON string to Associative array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

What I'm trying to Do is so simple yet everything I tries had failed. I have the following string: `"{"msg":"background1.jpg"}"`, and I want to convert it to an array to access the `msg` value. this should simply be done like so(or so I've thought):

```
$theString = "{"msg":"background1.jpg"}";

var_dump(json_decode($theString, TRUE));
```

The `vr_dump()`  is dumping `NULL`, also tried:

```
var_dump(json_decode(json_encode($theString), TRUE));
```

This dumps `string(45) "{"msg":"background1.jpg"}"`

and tried many many more things, but all failed. Any thought please.

EDIT:

I'm getting the json string from database, where i have previously stored like so:

```
$toBeStored = json_encode(array("msg" => $value));
```

Comment: your json seems incorrect

Comment: Why? whats wrong with it?

Comment: @Richie could you please see the edit, this is how I'm getting the string.

Comment: it should be like this `{"msg": "background1.jpg"}`

Comment: it is, the quotations are added by the `var_dump` and I just copied it as is from the console

Comment: If you are getting some problem then there are many online tools are available for json validation. [json validator](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: You need to escape your double quotes. Or, use single quotes on the outside.

Comment: there are no quotes, if I `echo` the variable containing the string it outputs `{"msg":"background1.jpg"}`, they are added by `var_dump`. The  json is valid for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$var = '{"msg": "background1.jpg"}';

var_dump($var);
```

`